# Слетает dll. Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, library

Подключил dll к форме windows.forms. Запускаю exe-шник - все работает.
Если вызываю форму из другой программы, то возникает ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключил dll через ссылки. Может есть другой способ подключения?

Comment: Версия дотнета какая?

Comment: .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: Меня одного смущает, что названия сборок разные? DLLForWForm и CandleAnalyzerDLL

Comment: к форме подключена DLLForWForm, a CandleAnalyzerDLL подключена к программе, которая вызывает эту форму

Comment: Как именно добавлена сборка? Версии дотнета везде одинаковые? И у либ и у программы? exe программы и либы в одной папке находятся? В bin/debug программы все либы, что надо, складываются?

Comment: Версии дотнета одинаковые. exe-формы и dll находятся в одной папке. Не bin/debug, в другой папке.